# How can print numbers is separate lines?

Tags: c, scanf, newline

The question to solve is that this code should get numbers in separate lines until 0 is given. Then it should print y number, y times. For example if number 3 is given, it should print 3, 3 times in  separate lines.
I try to get the inputs from the user in separate lines. I mean one input in one line. Then print the numbers in separate lines. I don't know where to add `\n` to solve it.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y = 1;
    while (y != 0) {
        scanf("%d", &y);
        if (y == (0)) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", y);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add `\n` beside `%d` of `scanf` but it didn't work as I expected.

The output of this code is like this:

```
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
0
```

What I expect is that all the inputs should be given in separate lines before output is printed.
input like this:

```
1
2
3
4
0
```

output like this:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should start with increasing your compiler warning level. For GCC or clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It should tell you that you are using `y` without initializing it: `while (y!=0)`. You should also always check return value of `scanf`. How would you know if a value was parsed properly if you don't care about status?

Comment: You only start the printing after the fist loop is left. If you want to print for each input, you need to move the second loop into the first loop body. Right after the `scanf`.

Comment: I edited it but it didn't work again.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Can you post the current output?

Comment: "one input in one line"; "I tried to add \n beside %d" Do you mean you want to force `scanf` to always parse from the start of a new line? And does that mean the program should ignore the remainder of the previous line, if any?

Comment: Please be precise what you want and what wrong output you get. Do you want to enter all the input before you start the output? Do you want to print after each input? Also please note that changing the code in question while there are already answers is a NO-GO! That invalidates all the effort people spent on your issue.

Comment: Its my first time that I'm using SO. I'm new. It might take time to understand. Yes I want to enter all the input before I start the output. @Gerhardh

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  Here what I suggest you do: delete the input and output sections, keep the actual output and then tell us what the corresponding expected output is supposed to be.

Comment: Half way there... now you need to tell us what the expected output is that correspond to the actual output.

Comment: @Coder Not really... we need input, output and expected output.  Because your session is interactive, your section is "The output of this code is like this:" is really input + output (which is ok) but then your expected data should be the same (input + expected output).  I suggest you relabel the first section, and then literally copy and paste that first section, then modify the copy to match you want.

Comment: @AllanWind I did. I copied the exact output in that section.

Comment: You provide us with "input + actual output" and presumably "input" and "expected output".  Your issue appears to be that you don't want the "input" and "expected output" interleaved so you show us what the expected "input + expected output" session looks like.  Like my revised answer.  Once we understand what you want, we will able to help you.  Most likely, btw, you are overthinking it, and your original code was fine.

Comment: In your updated question, the output is shown *In-Order*, e,g, input `1, 2, 3, 0` and output `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3` where before you showed input `3, 2, 1, 0` with output of `1, 2, 2, 3, 3. 3`. Which is correct? While with arrays, iterating in reverse order is simple, but for recursive calls, iterating in the same order as the input will require a second recursive function to reorient the output order. Double check requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As @DavidC.Rankin explains below, if you want to retain the input it means you have to store it somewhere.  It's usually in memory and either the original input string (`char []`) or you store the data in a format suitable for output like `int input[LEN]` that I use below.
Other options includes using a recursive function to store one number on the stack, or a file or an external service like a database (possible hosted in the cloud these days).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 5

int main(void) {
    // input
    int input[LEN];
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < LEN; i++) {
        if(scanf("%d",input + i) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(!input[i])
            break;
    }

    // output (copy of input other than 0)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%d\n", input[j]);
    }

    // output (repeated based on input)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < input[j]; k++) {
            printf("%d\n", input[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
1 # input
2
3
4
0
1 # output (copy of input other than 0)
2
3
4
1 # output (repeated based on input)
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

Here is the as close you can get with a recursive function and no arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_then_print() {
    // input
    int d;
    if(scanf("%d", &d) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(d) {
        // output before recursion
        printf("%d\n", d);        
        read_then_print();
    }

    // output after recursion
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", d);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    read_then_print();
}
```

and example session:

```
1 # input
1 # output before recursion
2 # input
2 # output before recursion
3 # ...
3
4
4
0
4 # output after recursion
4
4
4
3
3
3
2
2
1
```

Comment: We should only use loop and if. I cant use arrays. Thank you for your answer by the way. I edited my post so you can understand what the question was.

Comment: Allan, the comment under my answer says `"I should get all the inputs first, after 0 is entered it should print the numbers and give the output."` would seem to suggest he needs to buffer the input in an array and then loop (in reverse?) over the array outputting the each element the number of times of its value. I'm punting this one to you `:)` So you just need to add a nested loop in your final `for` loop to output `input[i]` times.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am trying, buddy, too bad you deleted your answer.

Comment: No worries -- you were right. I did just do the same as his code. Plus you have already done the heavy lifting on the array `:)`

Comment: @Coder - if you can't use arrays, the only other option to get the output printed it's number of times after `0` is entered in the reverse order of the input -- is to use a *Recursive* function. Have you covered those in class?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: Without arrays (or some other data structure like a `stack` a `list` or buffer holding `int` values) and without making use of a recursive function, there is no way to read , e.g. `3, 2, 1, 0` and not output any of the numbers until `0` is pressed and then output `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3`.   Your two choices are either (1) store the values for use later (data structure) or (2) use a recursive function that emulates the behavior by making another recursive-call each time `y != 0` and then after that *exit-condition* occurs, unwind the recursion printing the values. Can you help us out here?

Comment: @Coder Adding a restriction like "I cant use arrays." buried in a comment and not in the original post is not fair.  Such restrictions should be given clearly right away.  IAC, `"%d"` is an array - so it seems "I cant use arrays." overstates.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int y;
    do
    {
        
        scanf("%d",&y);
        
        for(int i = 1;i <= y;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", y);
        }
        
       
    }while(y != 0);
    
        
}
```

Use this one this might solve your problem.

Comment: It was the same unfortunately. It doesnt take all the inputs at the same time.

Comment: Please be aware that code-only answers without any explanation are considered low quality. You might add what you think is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to gather all the input before processing the lines and printing the results. You can use an array to store the input numbers and process them once you read a `0`.

Here is a modified version with this approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINES  256

int main() {
    int input[MAX_LINES];
    int y, n = 0;

    while (n < MAX_LINES && scanf("%d", &y) == 1 && y != 0) {
        input[n++] = y;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y = input[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```